# Connection error between IBM Message Broker (MB) and WSRR

Tags: message, messagebroker, wsrr

I tried every possible way to connect WSRR from IBM Message Broker (MB). But I am getting this exception every time.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><LookupResults><ServiceRegistry>Failure to retrieve Service from WSRR!</ServiceRegistry><Exception><RecoverableException><File>F:\build\S000_P\src\DataFlowEngine\ImbDataFlowNode.cpp</File><Line>1129</Line><Function>ImbDataFlowNode::createExceptionList</Function><Type>SRRetrieveITServiceNode</Type><Name>WSRR_Connectivity#FCMComposite_1_8</Name><Label>WSRR_Connectivity.Endpoint Lookup One</Label><Catalog>BIPmsgs</Catalog><Severity>3</Severity><Number>2230</Number><Text>Node throwing exception</Text><RecoverableException><File>F:\build\S000_P\src\DataFlowEngine\PluginInterface\com_ibm_broker_plugin_CMbService.cpp</File><Line>1860</Line><Function>ImbJavaExceptionUtils::throwableToNativeException</Function><Type></Type><Name></Name><Label></Label><Catalog>BIPmsgs</Catalog><Severity>3</Severity><Number>4367</Number><Text>Unhandled exception in plugin method.</Text><Insert><Type>5</Type><Text>evaluate</Text></Insert><Insert><Type>5</Type><Text>Endpoint Lo[/code]
```

Comment: This old question doesn't contain valid XML - since it cannot be sensibly formatted for readability, I am casting a close vote.

Answer (score 1):

The Java based SRRetrieveITServiceNode has thrown an exception and this has been wrapped in the parent BIP2230 exception when it was thrown across the JNI boundary between the SRRetrieveITServiceNode and the rest of the flow.

Unfortunately your pasted XML has truncated the rest of the exception stack but I would expect that the innermost exception in the stack will tell you the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IBM suggests the following solution:-

**Resolving the problem**

*Ensure the certificate in broker truststore is of X.509 format and that broker is pointing to a .jks truststore*

Comment: However, even though when I ensured that the broker is pointing to .jks trust store and the format is X 509, I am still facing the same error!